# Rails 7: Popover does not work when clicking submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popover

I'm working in an rails 7 application where a bootstrap popover should raise when an element is clicked. It was working until I added a form with a submit button. After that, the element does not "pops" after hitting the submit button (but works after refresh). I'd like to know why this happens and how can I fix it.

The application is rather big, so I tried to create a simple application where the problem appears.
I'll describe all the steps to create the application and the contents of the files:

1. versions:

> ruby -v
> ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]
> rails -v
> Rails 7.0.4.3

2. create application

> rails new popover --css=bootstrap

3. enter

> cd popover

4. generate controller

> bin/rails g controller test action

5. file app/javascript/application.js

   ```
    import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
    import "./controllers"
    import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

    let popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
    let popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl) })

    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl) })
   ```
6. file app/controllers/test_controller.rb

   ```
    class TestController < ApplicationController
      def action
        grr = params[:grr].present? ? params[:grr] : nil
      end
    end
   ```
7. file app/views/test/action.html.erb

   ```
   <div id="some-id">
   <%= form_tag('action',  :method => "get") do %>

   <fieldset class="">
       <legend class="">Type Something</legend>

       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="form-group">
           <%= label_tag "GRR: ",  nil, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label"   %>
           <%= text_field_tag :grr,  nil, class: "col-lg-4" %>
         </div>
         <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "col-lg-2 btn btn-primary "    %>
       </div>
   </fieldset>

   <%end%>

   <%= generate_popover %>
   ```

Popover works until you click the submit button. It works again after refresh page.

8. file app/helpers/test_helper.rb

   ```
    module TestHelper
      def generate_popover
        button_tag("click me to popover message",
           data: { bs_toggle: 'popover',
                   bs_html: 'true',
                   bs_content: "Popover Msg" })
      end
    end
   ```

I' like to know what causes the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this premise is correct:

- page loads with:

  - form for "GRR:"
  - buttton with data-bs_toggle="popover"

and:

- Before form submission, popover button works as expected
- After form submission, popover button does not work
- After page refresh, popover button works as expected

---

When the submit button is pushed the form is either:

- AJAXing the form data to the controller action
- performing a GET request to the controller action

Which ever one of those that is happening, it is breaking bootstrap's `eventListener` that is waiting for the button click.

Refreshing the page re-loads bootstrap's JS and the `eventListener` is re-established and the button works again as expected.

The fix is a bit trickier, but you've got to find a way to either prevent the eventListener from getting broken or force the `eventListener` to be re-established after form submission.

What I'd try first, especially if I didn't care about AJAX vs. GET, is to toggle my form's remote setting:

```
<%= form_tag('action',  method: "get", remote: true) do %>
<%= form_tag('action',  method: "get", remote: false) do %>
```

If one of those fixes it, I'd call it a win and move on. Much easier than messing with the JS.

---

### Update

try to specifically disable turbolinks on the `form_tag` or the `submit_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag('action',  method: "get", remote: false, data: { turbo: false }) do %>

<%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "col-lg-2 btn btn-primary", data-turbo: false %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately didn't work with either remote:

Comment: I added another solution: disabling turbolinks via the `data-turbo="false"` flag.

Comment: Disabling turbolinks worked!! Thanks!